# Calling the inherit and the base method

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

I have 2 classes

```
public class A
{
    public A(string N)
    {
        Name = N;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void GetName()
    {
        Console.Write(Name);
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public B(string N) : base(N)
    {
    }

    public new void GetName()
    {
        Console.Write(new string(Name.Reverse().ToArray()));
    }
}
```

I create a new object `B` which I want to call `GetName` from `A` and `GetName` from `B`

```
B foo = new B("foo");
foo.GetName(); //  output "oof"
```

Expected Output `"foooof"`

I already tried `public new void GetName() : base` but that does not compile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get your desired output you need to call the `base GetName()` method in the `GetName()` method of the `Class B`. Like this for example:

```
public class A
{
    public A(string N)
    {
        Name = N;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void GetName()
    {
        Console.Write(Name);
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public B(string N) : base(N)
    {
    }

    public new void GetName()
    {
        base.GetName();
        Console.Write(new string(Name.Reverse().ToArray()));
    }
}
```

This will out put `foooof`

Answer (score 2):

Use override and call the base class' method from the overridden method:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual void GetName()
    {
        Console.Write(Name);
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public override void GetName()
    {
        base.GetName();
        Console.Write(new string(Name.Reverse().ToArray()));
    }
}
```

The `virtual` keyword is used to modify a method and allow for it to be overridden in a derived class whereas the `new` modifier hides the base class method. By calling the `base.GetName();` you are executing the base method BTW, this is why it has no difference that you use the `new` or `override` keywords here although I recommend that use `override`.

References:

[virtual (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx)

[Knowing When to Use Override and New Keywords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153.aspx)

Comment: `base.GetName();` seems to work without `override` too

Comment: @GodofSource The virtual keyword is used to modify a method and allow for it to be overridden in a derived class. So you could combine the `GetName`'s result like mentioned in the code above.

Comment: @GodofSource The override modifier extends the base class method, and the new modifier hides it. By calling `base.GetName();` you are executing the base method BTW this is why it has no difference that you use `new` or `override` here. But you should know that with `new` you hided the base method but with override you extended it.

Comment: @GodofSource `new` is dangerous. Don't use it if you don't know what you are doing.

Comment: what means "extend"?

Comment: @GodofSource It means the implementation of a base method can be changed by an overriding method in a derived class.

Comment: @GodofSource I included explanation in the answer. Check updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class A
{
    public A(string N)
    {
        Name = N;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual void GetName()
    {
        Console.Write(Name);
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public B(string N) : base(N)
    {
    }

    public override void GetName()
    {
        base.GetName();
        Console.Write(new string(Name.Reverse().ToArray()));
    }
}
```

Use override or new according to your choice.
Like to handle these scenarios.

```
            A foo = new B("foo");
            foo.GetName();
```

or

```
            A foo = new A("foo");
            foo.GetName();
```

or

```
            B foo = new B("foo");
            foo.GetName();
```

this [msdn link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153(v=vs.80).aspx) will give you clear picture.